# Can ggplot titles contain line breaks (when used with ggtext)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "This is a Title\n") +
  theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
        plot.title = element_markdown(), 
        legend.position = "none")
```

Why can't I add a line break to my ggplot title to get some white space between the title and panel? I know there's other ways to achieve this padding, but I want to limit this question explicitly to line break methods for adding white space.

I'm almost certain I've done this before for axis titles to add white space between the axis title and plot panel. Why won't `\n` work in the plot title?

[image]

---

*Edit with additional information based on comments*

This code chunk will break a title into two lines.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Line Number One\nLine Number Two") +
  theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

This "almost identical" code chunk won't. The big question... **Why?** I imagine in Markdown I need the `<br>` or maybe two spaces? to break the line?

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "The First Line\nThe Second Line") +
  theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
        plot.title = element_markdown(), 
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `labs(title = "The First Line  \nThe Second Line")` work with `element_markdown()`. In Markdown you usually need two spaces before the newline to make a line break.

Comment: @MrFlick adding two spaces before `\n` in R Studio `labs(title = "The First Line  \nThe Second Line")` worked. If I simply want to add white space padding without a second line you have to `labs(title = "The First Line  \n&nbsp;")` and that will also work. Do you want to write that as an answer and I can mark solved? I'll also upvote @Maurits Evers answer/comments because Maurits's answer and comments were quite helpful as well.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

### Option 1 - With `ggtext`

Use `<br>`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "This is a Title<br>Another line") +
  theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
        plot.title = element_markdown(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

The nice thing with `ggtext` is that you can use a lot of markdown/HTML syntax to highlight/colour/theme text in `ggplot2` titles & labels.

### Option 2 - Plain `ggplot2`

Use `\n`

```r
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "This is a Title\nAnother line") +
  theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: @Maurits Evers your solution does work, but strange enough if I change the title in my original example to `"This is a Title\nAnother Line"` the `Another Line` does _not_ plot on a second line. Must be some type of conflict between my latest version of ggplot (ggplot2_3.3.0.9000) and ggtext (ggtext_0.1.0) and my unique combination of code. Or perhaps something else I haven't thought of. Maybe my question is really a bug report?

Comment: @JasonHunter I may have misunderstood you. You need to use `<br>` when using `element_markdown()` to enforce a line break. `\n` won't work.

Comment: @Maurits Evers if I try to apply your option #2 (preferred method) I'm unable to. I've edited the original question to try and demonstrate this. I hope my intent is decipherable.

Comment: @JasonHunter Thanks for clarifying. I don't know what `element_markdown()` does under the hood (Claus Wilke should be able to clarify); but `\n` not working with `element_markdown()` seems to be consistent with `\n` not working in a markdown (or HTML) document. In other words: You wouldn't use `\n` to enforce a linebreak in markdown either, would you.

Comment: [continued] From the [`ggtext` GH site](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext): *"[`element_markdown()`] render[s] the provided text as markdown/html."* Markdown does not recognise `\n` as a linebreak.

Comment: So you could also do `labs(title = "This is a Title  \nAnother line")` with ggtext, right? (have those two spaces in there before the break)

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, I currently don’t have access to a computer so can’t test. Wouldn’t you usually do a line break in markdown with two spaces followed by return? Not sure if two spaces would work.

Comment: Yes. Two spaces. But I realized that if I put two spaces in the code, HTML will only render one. I needed to put in nbsp codes for the comment. So maybe that just make it more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two spaces followed by 'Return':

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "This is a Title  
       This is a new line  
       ") +
  theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
        plot.title = element_markdown(), 
        legend.position = "none")
```

`title = "This is a Title  \r\nThis is a new line"` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the simplest solution to add two spaces prior to the `\n`, and I also needed to add a non-breaking space after the line break to get the padding:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "This is a Title  \n&nbsp;") +
  theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
        plot.title = element_markdown(), 
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image: solution]

Comment: Not sure I agree with two spaces followed by `\n` as being the "simplest solution"; `<br>` is a single HTML tag with as many characters; so from a code-golfing point-of-view they rank equally. (I'm ignoring your additional `&nbsp`, which makes it decidedly "un-simple"). But obviously this will depend on your personal preference;-)

Comment: @Maurits Evers you are correct, and perhaps my use of language is somewhat sloppy. I could've said that this answer works best for me (vs "it's simpler"). I used to use `<br>` in R Markdown to add white space to plots. There were some edge cases... and I can barely remember... but I was using blogdown, kableExtra, some other packages and was having issues with `<br>`. But was able to use Markdowns "two spaces" to break lines successfully. Since then I've avoided `<br>` in any type of R Markdown. With limited info I think this answer will work better for my use cases, but it remains to be seen.

Comment: No worries Jason:-) Interesting to hear that `<br>` may cause issues in combination with other packages, will keep that at the back of my mind.